# Send javascript code as data in Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send data by ajax request to PHP file. The data contain HTML code and javascript code too.

I tried like that:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         $.ajax({
            url: 'http://page.com/file.html',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res) {
                value = res.responseText;

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://my-page.com/file.php',
                    data: {
                        html: value
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(res)
                    {
                        $('#cont').html(res);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

But ajax send to PHP file only HTML code without javascript code.
How I can fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `res.responseText;` return ?

Comment: hmm. Good question. The problem is in: "res.responseText" - it doesn't return javascript code and here is a problem. So how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What is _expected_ return value of `res.responseText` ? , appear to be requested from an `html` document `'http://page.com/file.html'` ? , is `js` expected to be included in response from `'http://page.com/file.html'` ?